Kubernetes - "Whitelisted" Node Pool Implementation?
Is it possible to create a node pool which will only accept deployments from "marked" deployments?
I know that you can tag a deployment not to be scheduled on a given pool, but I would like to create a pool to be used by a single deployment without having to update all my other deployments to not use the new pool...

You can check this sample yaml from docs that you can use:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  tolerations:
  - key: "example-key"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoSchedule"

If you're using GKE, you can follow this guide to create node taints

You can use node taints, with a matching toleration for a selected deployment.
